# Logparser query does not give me any output

Tags: logparser

I have multiple domains in my organization. I am trying to run a query on message tracking logs to find emails delivered from certain domains. I am sure there would be thousands of emails delivered, however I am not get any output. I am using the query as below.

```
"SELECT event-id,recipient-address,sender-address from *.log where event-id like 'DELIVER' AND recipient-address LIKE '%@abc.com%' AND recipient-address LIKE '%xyz.com%' AND recipient-address LIKE '%123.com'" -i:CSV -nSkipLines:4 -rtp:-1 >>D:\TEST_Accepted_Domain.csv
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It seems to me your LIKE clauses should be joined with OR's: `recipient-address LIKE '%@abc.com%' OR recipient-address LIKE '%xyz.com%' ...`

Answer (score 1):

A good way to debug this is to change your query to, say, `SELECT TOP 10 ...` to limit the number of results.  Then try without the WHERE clause, and if this returns rows, add in the WHERE conditions one at a time until you understand what's going wrong.

In your example, one problem is that you are using AND where you should be using OR.  Try:

```
SELECT ... from *.log 
where event-id like 'DELIVER' AND 
(recipient-address LIKE '%@abc.com%' 
 OR recipient-address LIKE '%xyz.com%' 
 OR recipient-address LIKE '%123.com'
) ...
```